Can I apply for new Schengen visa if old expired without being used?
Can I apply for new Schengen visa if old expired without being used? Do I need to do an interview again?

Yes, you need to apply for a new visa if the old one expires before you need it. The interview depends on the consular post where you're applying, some will require an interview, some will not.

It is probably worth mentioning the reason for non-use of the previous visa in the new application.

@DJClayworth Would they even know that you didn't use it?

@PMF They will know, just by checking entry stamps. Usually non-use is not an issue. There can be any number of reason you have to cancel or postpone a trip.
